# Multiple columns in where clause is not working in hive

Tags: hive

Example 1:

```
Select * from table1 A 
Inner join table2 B On A.id =B.id 
And (A.name,A.Roll_no) not in (select name,roll_no from table2)
```

Example 2:

```
Select * from table A 
where (A.id,A.name,A.Roll_no) in( Select I'd,name,roll_no from table B )
```

If I'm using two or more columns in the where clause to fetch the result subquery then the query does not run.

Answer (score 0):

Hive join works with [equality_expression](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins) only .

If you need to filter result using not in put that condition in [where claus](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)e.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table A 
where concat(A.id,A.name,A.Roll_no) in( Select concat(I'd,name,roll_no) from table B )
```

Comment: Please, explain what your solution does, how it works, do not throw a chunk of code as an answer. At the moment it is not a great answer.